# Unable to access images and CSS file in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using my old website design code in a new app. The problem is I didn't use the HTML helper for loading images. I am using the HTML image tag `<img style="width:95px; margin-top:20px;"src="images/logo.png" />`. It works fine in this link http://localhost/dashboard/dboard/ but doesn't work in this link http://localhost/dashboard/dboard/pages/demo. Pages is a controller and demo is a method in the controller.

My `PagesController` look like this:-

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
class PagesController extends AppController
{


    public function display()
    {
        $path = func_get_args();
    enter code here`enter code here`
        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingTemplateException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }


     public function demo()
    {

    }
    public function contactus()
    {

    }
    public function downloads()
    {

    }
}
```

And my .htaccess file look like this:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The important thing is I have placed all my images here: C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\webroot. I am using CakePHP 3.0.

The output looks like this:-

[image: with working css and images]
[image: without working css and images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that apache is trying to search images in the path `<app_folder>/webroot/pages/dashboard/images` as you could probably see if you check the 404 errors in a web developer console (in Chrome press F12).

You can solve this two ways:

- by replacing the img tags with calls of the HtmlHelper::img method (which would be a little bit harder on the beginning since you used inline styles (but is the best fix you can do)) [ You should really consider as well refactoring the inline styles to classes in a external stylesheet];
- Or prepending the base url in the `src` like this:

`<img src='<?php echo Router::url('/') ?>/images/picture.png' >`

This way the final url would look like:

http://localhost/dashboard/dboard/images/picture.png

And your files will be found.

Comment: The HTML helper should really be used and won't cause an issue with using inline styles, you can set the `style` attribute the same as any other `<img />` attribute with the helper.

Comment: I expressed myself in a wrong way. By trouble I meant more work if compared using the second solution. I will update my answer.

Comment: Using the HTML helper would still be preferable. I've had various issues using the `<img />` tag directly rather than including images using the HTML helper.

Comment: @PedroTanaka ya am html helper and its work fine now and i also tried Router::url('/') it too work thanks for ur help dude